# Proving Optimal Greedy Algorithms

Tags: algorithms, proof-techniques, greedy-algorithms, correctness-proof

How is the best way to go about proving that a greedy algorithm is optimal, inductive vs contradiction, are there parts in the proof that are key to include. I did not feel that the lesson  I was given adequately covered how to start a greedy proof, any advise on a general way to go about proving greedy algorithms would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.